# Regex for filenames in html anchor tag

Tags: c#, html, regex, wildcard, filenames

I have the following code:

```
string regexStr = "<a href=\"" + URL + "*.pdf";
regexStr = Regex.Escape(regexStr);
Regex regex = new Regex("^" + regexStr + "$");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);
```

I have a parent HTML page that contains a list of directories. Usually the latest dated directory contains a list of files as such:

[image]

But sometimes, the directory is empty, so then I need to check the next latest dated directory, look for the list of files, and if there are files there, use that directory.

This is an HTML page so the files, when listed, are an anchor tag like the following:

So I'm "simply" trying to use Regex to search for [a href="/d-tpp/2204/*.pdf">]

I can't seem to get the Regex right to make a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
var regex = new Regex($"<a\\s+href=\"({Regex.Escape(URL)}[^\"]*?\\.pdf)");
var matches = regex.Matches(html).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

**NOTE**

- The `*.pdf` part is wrong, `*` is a quantifier, and you need to match any chars other than a `"` char as few as possible, i.e. `[^"]*` pattern
- `regexStr = Regex.Escape(regexStr)` is wrong, you should never `Regex.Escape` regular expression patterns, you only need to use `Regex.Escape` to escape literal texts passed to the regex pattern
- `new Regex("^" + regexStr + "$")` is also wrong since you are looking for partial *multiple* matches inside a long string, and `^`  with `$` anchor the matches to the whole string.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/faor7S):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = "000.pdf <a href=\"/d-tpp/2204/1.pdf\"> 1111.pdf <a href=\"/d-tpp/2204/2.pdf\"> 2222.pdf";
        var URL = "/d-tpp/2204/";
        var regex = new Regex($"<a\\s+href=\"({Regex.Escape(URL)}[^\"]*?\\.pdf)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matches = regex.Matches(html).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
        foreach (var s in matches)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/d-tpp/2204/1.pdf
/d-tpp/2204/2.pdf
```

Comment: How do I test matches? I keep getting type conversion errors.

Comment: @JimBeaumont See the update.